# Is it possible to evaluate this integral? If not, is it possible to determine whether the result is an elliptic function or not?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals, polylogarithm

I am trying to evaluate the integral

$$F(x,y) = \int_0^1 du_1\, \int_0^{1-u_1} du_2\, \frac{\log f(x,y|u_1,u_2)}{f(x,y|u_1,u_2)}\,, \tag{1}$$

with

$$f(x,y|u_1,u_2) := u_1(1-u_1)+y\, u_2(1-u_2) + (x-y-1)u_1 u_2\,, \tag{2}$$

where $0<x<1, 0<y<1$.
My question is simple: **is it possible to evaluate this integral for general $x$ and $y$?**

Mathematica returns a result for the first integral, which takes the form

$$F(x,y) = \int_0^1 du_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\ldots}} (\text{arctanh} (\ldots) + \log (\ldots) + \text{Li}_2 (\ldots))\,. \tag{3}$$

I cannot specify the $\ldots$ here because the expressions are very lengthy.
I have been told in the past that $1/\sqrt{\ldots}$ can be a sign of the function being elliptic. **Is it possible to say whether $F(x,y)$ is an elliptic function or not?**

Comment: You have been told wrong, this is not a sign of anything. Sure, if there were a 4th degree polynomial under the root, and nothing else on top, then that would be hinting at an elliptic function. Short of that, no.

Comment: It is not hinting at an "elliptic function", but at an "elliptic integral".  But as Ivan said, with that arctanh, $\log$, etc. in there, it is probably not an elliptic integral.

Comment: Where does this question come from? Did you make it up yourself?